# Flashing stock rom through cwm

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, root-access, samsung, stock-android

Can I flash a stock rom through cwm? I have a rooted Galaxy Mega, with cwm installed and want to upgrade to the new kit kat samsung firmware.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for flashing stock Samsung firmware is through Odin on your PC with the original USB cable. This will remove the root and return your device in stock condition with the desired downloaded Android version.
The process is very easy you just have to flash the MD5 file using ODIN in download mode you can follow this useful guide with images [Samsung Stock Firmware downloading and flashing guide](http://www.siteawy.com/en/mobile/samsung-original-software-download-install-flash.html)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).